# PrimeFaces Tree - show different context menu when selecting multiple nodes

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, tree

I'm working on a PrimeFaces web app. I just started getting into it so bear with me.

I have a Tree with multiple types of nodes - each with their own context menu.
My problem is that I want to be able to show different context menus when a single node is selected and when multiple are.
The Tree's selection mode should obviously be `multiple`.

Code:

```
    <!-- Here should be context menu for when multiple nodes are selected -->
    <!--        <p:contextMenu for="tree"> -->
    <!--            <p:menuitem value="Multiple Items Selected"> -->
    <!--            </p:menuitem> -->
    <!--        </p:contextMenu> -->

    <p:contextMenu for="tree" nodeType="type1">
        <p:menuitem value="Type 1 Selected">
        </p:menuitem>
    </p:contextMenu>

    <p:contextMenu for="tree" nodeType="type2">
        <p:menuitem value="Type 2 Selected">
        </p:menuitem>
    </p:contextMenu>

    <p:contextMenu for="tree" nodeType="type3">
        <p:menuitem value="Type 3 Selected">
        </p:menuitem>
    </p:contextMenu>

    <p:tree id="tree" value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node"
        selectionMode="multiple">
        <p:treeNode type="type1">
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
        </p:treeNode>

        <p:treeNode type="type2">
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
        </p:treeNode>

        <p:treeNode type="type3">
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: any updates on this question? This one is very interesting since the primefaces user guide doesn't mention anything about this

Comment: @Fritz I did solve this.. Added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this purely in the client side by changing the CSS of the menu items I wanted to hide.

I used a single context menu both for single selection and multiple but I hide the items I don't want to show for multiple selection.
Every menu item I wanted to hide in case of multiple selection got a `style="class: multiple_tree_cm;"`.
I used the context menu event on the tree.

Example tree:

```
<p:tree id="tree" widgetVar="treeWV">
    <p:ajax event"contextMenu" onstart="updateTreeContextMenu();"/>
     <p:treeNode .../>
</p:tree>
```

example context menu:

```
<p:contextMenu for="tree">
    <p:menuitem ... styleclass="multiple_tree_cm"/> <!-- don't want to show this for multiple selection -->
</p:contextMenu>
```

I hide the menu items by adding a css class to the multiple_tree_cm class menu items.
Like this:

```
function updateTreeContextMenu(event) {
    if (PF('treeWV') && PF('treeWV').selections && PF('treeWV').selections.length === 1) {
        $('.multiple_tree_cm').removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
        $('.multiple_tree_cm').addClass('disabled');
    }
}
```

css:

```
.multiple_tree_cm {}
.disabled { height: 0 !important; display: none !important; }
```